# bootstrap 5: display multiple form input-group inline

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

How can one display multiple form input-groups inline with Bootstrap 5?

Tried this, but input group components show on top of each other:

```html
<div class="container">
Your username is
<div class="input-group form-control-inline">
  <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Username">
</div>
and your email <is></is>
<div class="input-group form-control-inline">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline" placeholder="">
  <span class="input-group-text">@example.com</span>
</div>

</div>
```

```css
.form-control-inline {
   display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -8px;
}

.form-control-inline.form-control, .form-control-inline.input-group-text {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/46se871g/

Comment: You can do it with use Inline form methods. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/layout/#inline-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used **flex** to help me achieve what you need. as flex gives more controls from the parent to the entire child for your HTML. read more details for [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

Also, I moved the text into the **.input-group** class to have every **div** with all of it's content.

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="input-group">
    Your username is
      <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
     and your email <is></is>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline" 
      placeholder="">
      <span class="input-group-text">@example.com</span>
     </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-group {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
}
```